# java.util.LinkedList causing infinite loop/OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java

I'm implementing Cloneable with one of my classes, and I need to make a shallow copy (yes, only shallow) of a java.util.LinkedList to do it.  I tried using

```
myList.clone() //myList is a java.util.LinkedList<myType>
```

but that was causing my program to stall, so I switched to using the copy constructor:

```
new LinkedList<myType>(myList)
```

but it still hangs up. Now this was only happening with a myType that was an enum, but now I just had the same error with a non- enum type, though now that I think of it that type has an inner enum type.  this has happened both on Sun's jdk 1.6 and openjdk 1.6.  I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what I'd be doing that would break LinkedList.  It's not throwing an Exception until it eventually runs out of memory, (usually I kill it before this happens).  Anyway, any ideas what might be causing this?

here is the clone method:

```
public Note clone(){
    List<Accidental> retAcc=new LinkedList<Accidental>();
    for(Accidental acc:accidentals)retAcc.add(acc.clone());
    return new Note(retAcc,position,restFlag,new LinkedList<TieType>(beginTies),new LinkedList<TieType>(endTies),tripFlag,duration);
}
```

TieType is an enum type, Accidental implements Cloneable and its clone() method is reproduced below.  position, restFlag, tripFlag, and duration are all primitives

```
public Accidental clone(){
    return new Accidental(acType,fltPosition);

}
```

acType is an inner enum type, fltPosition is is a float, these initialize the only two fields in accidental.

the problem is happening in the last line of the Note.clone() method when I call the LinkedList copy constructor.  This used to be a call to LinkedList.clone, but I changed it in an attempt to avoid this problem.  Here is the stack trace for this error (there is no error here, as I suspended the thread when it froze, rather than waiting for it to run out of memory, but as you can see, it was in the middle of the LinkedList copy constructor)

> LinkedList.(Collection) line: 115
>   Note.clone() line: 86
>   Note.simplify(int) line: 98
>   Note.split(int, List, List) line: 179
>   ManagedPart$Measure.adjustRemaining(int) line: 378 
>   ManagedPart$Measure.add(Note) line: 349
>   ManagedPart$Measure.access$1(ManagedPart$Measure, Note) line: 345
>   ManagedPart.addNote(Note) line: 216
>   PartEditor$EditPanel$3.actionPerformed(ActionEvent) line: 104
>   JButton(AbstractButton).fireActionPerformed(ActionEvent) line: 2012
>   AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(ActionEvent) line: 2335 
>   DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(ActionEvent) line: 404
>   DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(boolean) line: 259
>   BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(MouseEvent) line: 253
>   JButton(Component).processMouseEvent(MouseEvent) line: 6108
>   JButton(JComponent).processMouseEvent(MouseEvent) line: 3276
>   JButton(Component).processEvent(AWTEvent) line: 5873
>   JButton(Container).processEvent(AWTEvent) line: 2105
>   JButton(Component).dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent) line: 4469
>   JButton(Container).dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent) line: 2163
>   JButton(Component).dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) line: 4295
>   LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Component, int, MouseEvent) line: 4461
>   LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(MouseEvent) line: 4125 
>   LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) line: 4055
>   MusedDesktopClient(Container).dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent) line: 2149
>   MusedDesktopClient(Window).dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent) line: 2478
>   MusedDesktopClient(Component).dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) line: 4295
>   EventQueue.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) line: 604
>   EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(int) line: 275
>   EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(int, Conditional, EventFilter) line: 200
>   EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(int, Conditional, Component) line: 190
>   EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(int, Conditional) line: 185 
>   EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Conditional) line: 177
>   EventDispatchThread.run() line: 138

Also recently, I've had a similar problem with the construction of the LinkedList in the first line of Note.clone() i. e.

```
List<Accidental> retAcc=new LinkedList<Accidental>();
```

here is the stack trace for that:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>     at java.util.LinkedList.(LinkedList.java:95)
>     at com.mused.util.noteMgmt.Note.clone(Note.java:84)
>     at com.mused.util.noteMgmt.Note.simplify(Note.java:98)
>     at com.mused.util.noteMgmt.Note.split(Note.java:179)
>     at 
>   com.mused.util.noteMgmt.ManagedPart$Measure.adjustRemaining(ManagedPart.java:378)
>     at com.mused.util.noteMgmt.ManagedPart$Measure.insert(ManagedPart.java:335)
>     at com.mused.util.noteMgmt.ManagedPart.insertNote(ManagedPart.java:223)
>     at com.mused.gui.editor.PartEditor.currentIndexChanged(PartEditor.java:161)
>     at com.mused.gui.NoteViewer.fireIndexChangeEvent(NoteViewer.java:178)
>     at com.mused.gui.NoteViewer.setCurrentIndex(NoteViewer.java:417)
>     at com.mused.gui.NoteViewer.updateSelected(NoteViewer.java:627)
>     at com.mused.gui.NoteViewer.mouseMoved(NoteViewer.java:725)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Component.java:6153)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(JComponent.java:3294)
>     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5877)
>     at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2105)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4469)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2163)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4295)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4461)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4138)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4055)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2149)
>     at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4295)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:604)
>     at 
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
>     at 
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)

Comment: How do you know the clone() call is the culprit?  Please post a stack trace and enough of the class you're writing (the one that implements Cloneable) for us to see what's happening.

Comment: Including the entire clone() method.

Comment: Can you write a small test case and reproduce the issue?  If so, post it here.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can reproduce it in a test case, because it only happens some of the time, and I'm not entirely sure under what conditions it occurs.  I'm not necessarily looking for an answer in terms of what <i>is</i> going on since that would require more knowledge of this program than I can realistically give here.  I'm just looking for a brainstorm on what general sort of problem might cause LinkedList to stall like this rather than failing gracefully with an Exception (I'm hoping the list of such problems is relatively small).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out.  I had thought that I was doing something that caused an infinite loop in LinkedList, but what actually happened was that i wrote an infinite loop that included calls to LinkedList methods, and it just happened that whenever I suspended the thread or the system ran out of memory, it was during the execution of a LinkedList method.
Apparently those must take longer to execute than the rest of the code inside the loop or something.  Because it was always in LinkedList when I looked at the stack trace, I assumed I was somehow breaking LinkedList, when in actuality my broken code was simply calling LinkedList methods repeatedly until I stopped it or it ran out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with LinkedList::clone().  If it's hanging, then your list is corrupt, having somehow formed a circular link.  Here's an exerpt of the only relevant code from [java/util/LinkedList.java](http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/LinkedList.java.htm):

```
for (Entry e = header.next; e != header; e = e.next)
    clone.add(e.element);
```

This is the same algorithm used for LinkedList::toArray(), so if clone() hangs, then so should this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myList.toArray()));
```

If that hangs, your list is corrupt.  The most likely culpret would be **syncronization issues**.  LinkedList is not thread safe.  Try synching your declaration like this:

```
List<myType> myList = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<myType>());
```

Comment: I'm not manually multithreading.  This is a swing application, so I know there is multithreading going on in the background, but I had been under the impression that all of my code would be executing in one thread, and I wouldn't need to deal with synchronization.  Is that wrong? If so, what calls to the swing api will result in spawning a new thread?

Comment: Incidetally, I never meant to imply that the problem was actually in LinkedList, I knew it was my fault somehow, I was just wondering how my code could cause an infinite loop to occur inside of LinkedList, and you seem to have answered that question.

Comment: I made the switch, and I'm still getting an issue.  actually, come to think of it, I should have seen that coming, since I had the issue when constructing an *empty* LinkedList.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the memory allocation options to the JVM? Specifically `-Xms` and `-Xmx`.  You could have just filled up all memory allocated by default.  Can you try with

```
-Xms256m -Xmx1024m
```

and see if it fails in the same place?

Comment: I tried that and it still freezes.  I'm not sure that it will run out of memory now, though my guess is it eventually will.  Thing is the Lists being copied contain very little data (I have verified this with a debugger) In fact in the case of the second error I mentioned, I'm constructing an <i>empty</i> list when it freezes.  I feel like this operation shouldn't be taking this much time and memory, error or no.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I let the thread that I had suspended continue, and it did in fact run out of memory eventually.  there definitely seems to be some sort of infinite loop going on, I just can't figure out what could be causing it.